# Right angle triangle - Logarithm Problem

Tags: logarithms

Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the legs and $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle, $c-b \neq 1$, $c+b \neq 1$ then $\log_{(c+b)}a+\log_{(c-b)}a=2\log_{(c+b)}a\log_{(c-b)}a$.

Comment: Where are you getting these problems?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of log,
this equation is the same as
$\frac{\log a}{\log{c+b} }
+\frac{\log a}{\log{c-b}}
=2\frac{\log a}{\log{c+b} }\frac{\log a}{\log{c-b}}
$.

Canceling $\log a$ 
and clearing fractions,
this becomes
$\log(c-b) + \log(c+b) = 2 \log a$
or $(c-b)(c+b) = a^2$
or $c^2-b^2 = a^2$
which is just Pyth's theorem.

Comment: thanks a lot ..that was great explanation.